# Find and replace all using regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help.

I need to append wrapped lines to where it used to belong.

INPUT:

```
HOST 00 0 00 00 0 9999 BBB_AAA 0 23 03 (RAM) (U)
(PKK) (LNA) (HLD) $
HOST 00 0 00 00 0 $
HOST 00 0 00 00 1 9999 AAA_AAA 0 32 03 (RAM) (U)
(PKK) (LNA) (HLD) $
```

REQUIRED OUTPUT:

```
HOST 00 0 00 00 0 9999 BBB_AAA 0 23 03 (RAM) (U) (PKK) (LNA) (HLD) $
HOST 00 0 00 00 0 $
HOST 00 0 00 00 1 9999 AAA_AAA 0 32 03 (RAM) (U) (PKK) (LNA) (HLD) $
```

I use Reg Expression

Find what : `^\(.*`

Answer (score 0):

```
Find what: (\(U\))\s+(\(PKK\))
Replace with: $1 $2
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

Find what: `(?<!\$)\n`
Replace with: `nothing`